# rails select_tag selected value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For the code given below I wanted to keep the select box selected with the value that is passed.

But this doesn’t work:

```
@yrs =[2011,2010,2009,2008]
<%= select_tag 'year', options_for_select([["Select" , "" ]] + @yrs.to_a,:selected=>2011) %>
```

Please advise me how to go about it.

Answer (score 106):

Remove the `:selected=>`  part.

**Syntax:**

```
options_for_select(@options, @selected_options)
```

**Usage:**

```
options_for_select(1..5, 3)  # creates a range 1..5 , with 3 as selected by default
```

[Documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select)

Answer (score 33):

```
<%= select_tag "page_type", options_for_select(@page_type.collect{ |u| [u.data_name, u.id]}, :selected=>@page.page_type), {:class =>"select_combobox",:onchange=>"reset_form(this.id,'page_type_msg');"} %>
```

this works for me :)

Answer (score 6):

Just to clarify @M Tariq Aziz answer:

Your code should look like this:

```
@yrs =[2011,2010,2009,2008]
<%= select_tag 'year', options_for_select([["Select" , "" ]] + @yrs.to_a,2011) %>
```

The general format for select tag is:

```
<%= select_tag 'year', options_for_select(:collection, :selected) %>
```

Comment: I had an integer as a key value as was using a string as the selected value.  Where you used to_a I needed to use to_i.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  This worked for me: <%= select_tag(:map_set_priority_filter, options_for_select(MapSet.priority_filters.collect {|priority| [priority.name, priority.id]}, @map_set_priority_filter.to_i)) %>

Answer (score 0):

I was using a select box as part of a Search bar, so wanted to have the default first option selected on first presentation of the form, but then retain the chosen option thereafter. This works great:

```
<% styles = Styles.all.sort %>
<%= form_tag styles_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <p>
        Search: style
        <%= select_tag :search_style, options_for_select(styles, selected: params[:search_style]) %>
         with colour
        <%= text_field_tag :search_color, params[:search_color] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```