# How to use grouped_options_for_select with parent/child categories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table of categories and subcategories managed by the acts_as_tree gem. Each category has a name and a parent_id. I wish to put them in to an optgroup that looks like this. Only the children can be selected.

- Parent 1

  - Parent 1 Child 1
  - Parent 1 Child 2
  - Parent 1 Child 3
- Parent 2

  - Parent 2 Child 1
  - Parent 2 Child 2
  - Parent 2 Child 3

This dropdown then go into posts/new.html.erb so that new posts can be tagged to a category.

In the category table, there are only 2 columns. category_name and parent_id.

What's the best way to do this? I thought of something like this:

```
<%= select_tag :category, grouped_options_for_select(category_option_groups) %>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you retrieve the childs.

```
parent1.children # => [Parent 1 Child 1, Parent 1 Child 2, Parent 1 Child 3]
parent1child1.parent # => parent1
```

Now in your controller action, I do not know how you want to derive the parent, so feel free to adopt the best option for your case. So with this scenario I am considering that there will some previous action where you select the parent... but I can edit this based on the information you will provide.

```
class controller 

 def action
   @parent = Category.find(input_params)
   @childs = @parent.children
 end

 private
 def input_params
   params.require(:parent).permit(:firstfield, :secondfield)
 end
end
```

This is your select tag

```
<%= select_tag 'category', options_for_select(@childs, @selected_options) %>
```

[act_as_tree](https://github.com/erikdahlstrand/acts_as_tree)

[select_tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347039/rails-select-tag-selected-value#9352947)

Comment: I don't understand the part on finding by input_params. I don't see what fields I should be permitting since the list only has one field, which is category_name for the names of the categories and subcategories. I have also added some details to clarify what I need. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Joshua That is open for discussions, because I do not understand how you are suppore to show those fields. Do you have two select fields? One for Parent 1 and one for Parent 2 showing respectively P1C1, P1C2 and P1C3, while the other one P2C1, P2C2 and P2C3 or I should have the `@parent` variable calculated based on something? Thanks